# Fail build on Azure Powershell from Visual Studio Online build?

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm using Visual Studio Online to build my code.  I have an [Azure Powershell](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShell/RunAzurePowerShell.ps1) task which executes an exe that returns non-zero status code.  I successfully get back the non-zero status code and `exit` with this code, but the build still succeeds.  How do I fail the build from an Azure Powershell task?

```
& $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\the.exe
$e = $LASTEXITCODE
Write-Host "Exit code: $e"
if ($e -ne 0) {
    Write-Host "##[error]BUILD FAILED: $e"
}
exit $e
```

Output of the above is:

```
Exit code: 1
##[error]BUILD FAILED: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chris Patterson](https://twitter.com/chrisrpatterson) showed me that the Azure Powershell task wasn't launched by powershell.exe, and thus it didn't harvest the exit code.  He suggested I modify the code to this which solved the problem:

```
& $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\the.exe
$e = $LASTEXITCODE
Write-Host "Exit code: $e"
if ($e -ne 0) {
    Write-Error -Message "##[error]BUILD FAILED: $e"
}
exit $e
```

Note that `Write-Error` is enough to tell Visual Studio Online Build that something bad happened.  I've created [a Pull Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/pull/351) to the Azure task to make this happen on their side so this task behaves more like we'd expect.